# how to add multiple rows from datatable to crystal report

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with multiple rows. I want to bind this datatable to a crystal report .

How is it possible?

```
        Dsprint.Tables.Clear();
        Dsprint.Tables.Add(dtTitle);
        Dsprint.Tables.Add(dtitem);
        ReportDocument Rpt = new ReportDocument();
        string filepath = Application.StartupPath.Replace("bin\\Debug", "") +                   @"\CrystalReports\CryDayReport.rpt";
        Rpt.Load(filepath);
        frmCrystalReportViewer newReportViewer = new frmCrystalReportViewer();
        Rpt.SetDataSource(Dsprint);
        Dsprint.WriteXmlSchema(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\DayReport.xsd");
        newReportViewer.crViewer.ReportSource = Rpt;
        newReportViewer.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have two options**

> 1) Using Grouping

In this you can create group in Crystal report by ID and Suppress If Duplicate in this field's Property.

> 2)Suppress if Duplicate.

If Data is Order by ID then this option is also good. Just Right click id field and Select Property and check suppress if Duplicate.